# Oracle 11.1.0.7 Client throw ora-3113 and alert log show ora-3137

Tags: oracle

I have a database running in Oracle 11.1.0.7. When user tries to group transactions in larger amount (e.g. 100), then it’ll quickly hit the error and abend. I look on the alert log of the DB, it contains as below on and off.

```
Sun Dec 08 11:36:30 2013
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 43411 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 43411 mem# 0: +DATA_1/aedjp/onlinelog/group_1.799.774696121
  Current log# 1 seq# 43411 mem# 1: +ARCH_1/aedjp/onlinelog/group_1.9863.774696123
Sun Dec 08 11:36:31 2013
Archived Log entry 87110 added for thread 1 sequence 43410 ID 0x2300dcb5 dest 1:
Sun Dec 08 11:43:43 2013
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/aedjp/aedjp1/trace/aedjp1_ora_6940.trc:
ORA-03137: TTC protocol internal error : [12333] [254] [64] [42] [] [] [] []
```

What is the exact problem and what is the solution to this? Please advice.

Thanks
Lina

Comment: That is an oracle internal error.  Do you have paid support for Oracle?  You need to contact oracle support or  look on the oracle tech forum.  There is probably a patch available.

Comment: Yes, we do paid for Oracle. Thanks Old Programmer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open a support ticket. Period. This is

```
3137, 00000, "TTC protocol internal error : 
// *Cause:  TTC protocol internal error.
// *Action: Contact Oracle Support Services.
```

They mean it.

```
ORA-03113 
error is an unexpected end-of-file that occurred which could not 
be handled by SQL*Net.
```

This is almost always caused by by a db server error - in this case 3137.   These internal error codes cannot normally be correctly diagnosed except by oracle support staff.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I will log a case to Oracle.

Comment: There is replication process that replicates data to the Db, and it consistently have connection lost issues. It will throw Ora-3113. When the apps sends record in one by one, it lasts longer time and when the apps tries to group the transactions in larger amount(e.g:100), it quickly hit the error and abend. Looking in the alert log, it have ora-3137 on and off.